# Indexer method in an interface

Tags: c#, interface

How can I define an indexer method in an interface?

Comment: Is google blocked by your ISP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an interface with an indexer like so:

```
public interface Foo
{
    int this[int i] { get; set; }
}
```

Now any class that implements this interface needs to define an indexer with a getter and a setter.  The interface can't define an *implementation* of the indexer; it can only require classes that implement the interface to define one.

Comment: It's not redundant, it's invalid